# Prove that $\ln x\leq\frac{x^{x+1/x}-1}{2}$ [ not solved ]

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

Prove that $$\ln x\leq\frac{x^{x+1/x}-1}{2}$$ is true for every positive real number, without calculus/derivative . (i.e. using some inequalities)

---

**My progress.** For $x\geq 1$ using $x+1/x\geq 2$ we obtain $$\frac{x^{x+1/x}-1}{2}\geq\frac{x^{2}-1}{2}$$ So it suffices to prove $$\ln x\leq\frac {x^2-1}{2}$$ or $$x^2\geq 2\ln x+1$$ The inequality seems easier now. But, I am stuck here.

I don't have any approach for $0<x<1$.

Comment: Why do you want a proof without calculus ? I think to prove this inequality is not even easy with calculus.

Comment: @Peter My progress makes the inequality easier, right ?

Comment: The main difficulty will be to prove it for numbers near $1$ , since for $x=1$ we have an equality.

Comment: If $0<x<1$ then $x^{2x}>x^{x^2+1}.$

Comment: For $0<x<e^{-1/2}$ the inequality holds as RHS is greater than $-1/2.$

Comment: @Peter Do you have an approach use calculus ?

Comment: Can you clarify what your definition of $\ln(x)$ is? And if it relies on $e$, what your definition of $e$ is? Since you are asking to not use calculus, these things matter.

Comment: $\ln x\leq\frac {x^2-1}{2}$ has been proven e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2308466/42969, so this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 11):

**Update**: Thank @lone student for pointing out my mistake. I give a new proof.

**Supplement to Alex Ravsky's answer**.

We use the well-known inequality
$$\mathrm{e}^u \ge 1 + u, \quad \forall u \in \mathbb{R} \tag{1}$$
and the Bernoulli inequality
$$(1 + u)^r \ge 1 + ur, \quad \forall u > -1,\ r \ge 1. \tag{2}$$

Using (1),
we have $\ln x \le x - 1$.
It suffices to prove that
$$x^{x + 1/x} + 1 - 2x \ge 0. \tag{3}$$

Alex Ravsky has proved the case that $0 < x \le 1/2$ and $x\ge 1$.

It remains to prove the case that $1/2 < x < 1$.

Using (2) and $x + 1/x - 1 \ge 1$, we have
$$x^{x + 1/x - 1}
\ge 1 + (x - 1)(x + 1/x - 1). \tag{4}$$

From (3) and (4), it suffices to prove that
$$x\cdot [1 + (x - 1)(x + 1/x - 1)] + 1 - 2x \ge 0$$
or
$$x(x - 1)^2 \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Answer (score 6):

For $x>0$ we have $\ln x\le x-1 $ and  $x^{{x^2+1\over x}}\ge x^2$ for $x\ge 1.$ So it suffices to show that $2x-2\le x^2-1.$ The latter reduces to $(x-1)^2\ge 0.$ The justification of the inequality $\ln x\le x-1$ for $x> 0$  requires calculus methods.
[see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862356/proof-of-logarithm-inequality-without-continuity-fracx1x-le-ln1x-le)

Comment: Thank you, but for $x<1$ ?

Comment: At the moment I have no proof.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciated (+1).

Comment: I fixed the typo from the inequality. I am sorry for that typo.

Comment: If that is the final version, I can adjust my answer.

Comment: Yes exactly. I am sorry for that typo.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please ? You proved the inequality for $0<x<1$ too ?

Comment: No, the proof is restricted to $x\ge 1.$

Answer (score 5):

*This answer is partial.*

Consider the following graphs.

[image]

They suggest to split the required inequality into the inequalities $\ln x\le x-1$ and $x-1\le \frac{x^{x+1/x}-1}2$. Then first of them follows from the inequality $1+t\le e^t$, which holds for each real $t$. The second transforms into the inequality $2x-1\le x^{x+1/x}$. The latter holds when $0<x\le \tfrac{1}{2}$, because then the left-hand side nonpositive, whereas the right-hand side is nonnegative. The inequality also holds when $x\ge 1$, because then $x^{x+1/x}\ge x^2\ge 2x-1$.

Comment: Moreover, $y=2x-1$ is the common tangent line at $x=1$ to both $y=2\ln x-1$ and $y=x^{x+1/x}$. It is easy to show that $2\ln x-1$ is concave down on $(0,\infty)$, so the difficult part is to show (by hand) that $y=x^{x+1/x}$ is concave up on $(0,\infty)$. Mathematica shows that right away, since no roots of the second derivative of $x^{x+1/x}$ are real, and thus the convexity does not change. A bit of calculus also shows that the second derivative of $x^{x+1/x}$ at $x=1$ is $1>0$, so $x^{x+1/x}$ is concave up on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{x^{x+\frac{1}{x}}-1}2= \frac{e^{ln(x)(x+1/x)}-1}2 \ge  \frac{1+(ln(x)(x+\frac{1}{x})-1}2   =   0.5ln(x)(x+\frac{1}{x})  \ge  ln(x)$$

I used first order taylor of $e^x$.

And Am-Gm inequality.

only for $$x \ge 1$$

Comment: I think a little bit more work needs to be done justifying the first inequality because $\ln x$ could be negative and then things are a bit suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

For $\frac1{\sqrt{e}}<x<1:$

The inequality can be written as
$$\ln(1+2\ln x)\leq(x+\frac1x)\ln x.$$
On the left hand side, we use Maclaurin series approximation and then cancel $\ln x$ from both sides. Now, it is enough to prove that
$$2-2\ln x\geq x+\frac1x$$
on $I=(\frac1{\sqrt{e}}, 1)$. Or
$$2+2t>e^t+e^{-t}$$
on $(0,\frac12)$ which is true.

Comment: I think that the OP wants the proof without using calculus.

Comment: I deleted the parts involving derivative. İ hope it is not downvotable now. @Deif

Comment: I don't downvote posts.

Comment: I must iuse AM-GM inequality somewhere in my answer. @Deif